# partial_sort and smart pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, smart-pointers

I have a `SetPartitionVector` class which is derived from `vector<SetPartition>`. I'd like to `partial_sort` this vector using a custom comparison function but I have an error at compilation.

```
bool ScalableSummary::featuresDistComp(SetPartition cluster1, SetPartition cluster2){
    return (segmentClusters.AverageSOD(cluster1) > segmentClusters.AverageSOD(cluster2));
}

void ScalableSummary::selectLeastConsensualFeatures(const int p){
    partial_sort(segmentClusters.begin(), segmentClusters.begin() + p, segmentClusters.end(), featuresDistComp);
}
```

`segmentClusters` is a member of `ScalableSummary` of type `SetPartitionVector` which was filled this way :

```
SetPartition_ptr cluster;
...
segmentClusters.push_back(*cluster);
```

`SetPartition_ptr` is a smart pointer defined like this : 
`typedef boost::shared_ptr<SetPartition> SetPartition_ptr;`

This is the error I get from the compiler :

```
g++ -o ScalableSummary.o -c ScalableSummary.cpp -Iinclude -Wall -g
ScalableSummary.cpp: In member function ‘void ScalableSummary::selectLeastConsensualFeatures(int)’:
ScalableSummary.cpp:56:108: erreur: no matching function for call to ‘partial_sort(std::vector<SetPartition>::iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<SetPartition*, std::vector<SetPartition> >, std::vector<SetPartition>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
ScalableSummary.cpp:56:108: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5240:5: note: template<class _RAIter> void std::partial_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _RAIter)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5279:5: note: void std::partial_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<SetPartition*, std::vector<SetPartition> >, _Compare = bool (ScalableSummary::*)(SetPartition, SetPartition)]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5279:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘bool (ScalableSummary::*)(SetPartition, SetPartition)’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function object you pass to [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) needs to be either a callable object, or a function *pointer*. To make a function pointer you nedd to use the address-of operator `&`, just like when you make a pointer out of any other variable:

```
partial_sort(..., &featuresDistComp);
//                ^
//                |
// Note address-of operator here
```

Also, I hope your function is marked as `static`? You can't use non-static member functions as ordinary function pointers. The reason is that all non-static member functions have a hidden first arguments that is the `this` pointer inside the function. So either make sure the function is `static` or use e.g. [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...
partial_sort(..., std::bind(&ScalableSummary::featuresDistComp, this, _1, _2));
```

Comment: This is really sketchy and unclear. If you are really that much in a hurry, just make a comment.

Comment: @sehe I probably should have. Anyway, clarified it now.

Comment: I can't use a static function. The solution with `bind` is what I'm looking for. However, my understanding is that `std::bind` is only available with c++11. Is there a way to do this with boost?

Comment: @ElieGnrd [Boost Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html).